# Getting capturing group programatically in replaceAll

Tags: java, string, regexp-replace

I'd like to replace each occurrence of a regex within a string with a parsed `$1`. How can I do this?

```
    String line = "foo <<VAR>> bar <<VAR>>";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<<(\\w*?)>>").matcher(line);
    Map<String,String> replacements = Collections.singletonMap("VAR","REPLACEMENT");
    String replacedLine = matcher.replaceAll(replacements.get(?.group(1)));
    Assert.assertTrue("foo REPLACEMENT bar REPLACEMENT".equals(replacedLine));
```

Comment: why not just using the replaceAll method of String?

Answer (score 1):

You may use a [`Matcher#appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) method to build the result "as you match":

```
String line = "foo <<VAR>> bar <<VAR>> in <<NO>>";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<<(\\w+)>>").matcher(line);
Map<String,String> replacements = Collections.singletonMap("VAR","REPLACEMENT");
StringBuffer replacedLine = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    if (replacements.get(m.group(1)) != null)
        m.appendReplacement(replacedLine, replacements.get(m.group(1)));
    else
        m.appendReplacement(replacedLine, m.group());
}
m.appendTail(replacedLine);
System.out.println(replacedLine.toString()); // => foo REPLACEMENT bar REPLACEMENT in <<NO>>
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/6fk84J).

Answer (score 1):

Does this meet your need?

```
String line = "foo <<VAR>> bar <<VAR>>";

Map<String, String> replaceMap = new HashMap<>();
replaceMap.put("<<VAR>>", "REPLACEMENT");
//may be more replacement here

for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: replaceMap.entrySet()){
    line = line.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}

System.out.println(line); //<- foo REPLACEMENT bar REPLACEMENT
```

Comment: This is nice, but I discarded it because then you have to iterate each map value over all the lines, which in a big file seems quite inefficient

Comment: @Whimusical now I get you point, but if all the replacement is certain, `line.replaceAll()` could be replaced with `line.replace()` which I think should be faster, but still I don't know will it be more efficient than get all the regex matches, as I don't know how efficient the regex match is.